# Is there is `String.Format` method in Laravel 5?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.1, laravel-5

in C# .NET we have a function like below

```
String.format("abc{0}", " some text");
```

It will output final string like below.

> abc some text

Is there is `String.Format` method in Laravel 5?

Reason I asked this because I have below keys in .env file

```
UserFolder = public\User
```

and i want to add one more key below. SO in order to hardcode the images in code files, I want to do it in .env

```
UserFolder = public\User\{0}\images
```

Here `{0}` will be replaced with UserID

Answer (score 5, accepted):

PHP has the [built-in function sprintf](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php) which should have similar results.

In your example, usage would be:

The .env file:

`UserFolder = public\User\%s\images`

Usage in php:

`$folder = sprintf(env('UserFolder'), 'your user id here');`